# How can I keep the same index of the initially rendered list when users clicked on a filtered item in React Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack

I have included a filter (`filteredCat`) for my catalogue and it works as expected visually.

The issue is that although the items are filtered, the index being logged doesn't reflect the index of the new filtered list. It returns the index of the originally rendered list.

For example if the list is filtered down to a single item whose index was initially 10. It still logs the index of 0.

```
export default class Catalogue extends React.Component{

  productClickHandler(index){
    console.log(index);
  };

  render(){

let filteredCat = this.props.DVDLibrary.filter(
  (dvds) => {
    return(
      dvds.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.props.searchFilterInput) !== -1
    )
  }
);

var catologueList = filteredCat.map((dvds,index) => {
    return(
      <li key={index} onClick={this.productClickHandler.bind(this,index)}>
        <div className="inner">
          <h2>{dvds.title}</h2>
          <img src={dvds.image}/>
          <p><strong>Rating</strong>: {dvds.rating}</p>
          <p><strong>Price</strong>: {dvds.price}</p>
          <p><strong>Stock</strong>: {dvds.stock}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    )
});

return(
  <div>
    <ul>
      {catologueList}
    </ul>
  </div>
)
  }

}
```

How can I keep the same index of the initially rendered list when users clicked on a filtered item?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the **filteredCat** variable instead of the catologueList index works.